# I'm confused about PDF files

Tags: java, android, pdf

If I have my code this way round the PDF say's its invalid and cannot be opened, but if I swap them and have B before A it works fine? why is this and what would I have to do to get it working? TIA

```
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

//A
    String line = "";
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//B
    File directory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            File outputFile = new File(directory, "goo.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;//init length
            while (true) {
                try {
                    if (!((len1 = in.read(buffer)) != -1)) break;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You never close your `FileOutputStream`. It's possible that simply having the time delay of A causes some internal buffers to be flushed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I closed the FileOutputStream at the end and I'm still getting the same outcome.

Comment: What is `stream`?

Comment: just corrected it. 'stream' should have been 'in'.

Comment: Now that was quite an important detail, because without that it looks like the two pieces are entirely unrelated. Please take this example to learn how important it is to post the **actual code that you're executing** and not just an approximation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An InputStream can only be read once.

In 'A', the stream is read and the contents are put in a StringBuilder.
In 'B', the stream (now empty) is read and piped to a file.
By having A first, the output file will always be empty.

Simply remove A as it's not doing anything for you here.